# Disable stdout buffering in systemd, how to make it print everything?

Tags: linux, debian, systemd, daemon, stdout

On Debian, when I ask for service status, it only prints out a few lines:

```
sudo service tor status

        CPU: 3ms

Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Starting tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Finished tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

`sudo journalctl -u tor.service` has a tiny bit more

```
Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Stopped tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Stopping tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Starting tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master)...
Dec 15 17:57:27 systemd[1]: Finished tor.service - Anonymizing overlay network for TCP (multi-instance-master).
```

But still not the entire output.
For same reason I have to call

```
python3 -u test.py
```

In service files, otherwise it just sits on first line for hours.

It's impossible to debug without output. Of course commands work when I manually call them outside systemd.

**How can I make it more real time?** Or print all output within reasonable time?

Comment: That's where I got the -u from. It also say it's the source application's fault, BUT why doesn't it show up later even if it's buffered? Isn't there a periodic flush?

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't there a periodic flush?

Not periodic in terms of time, no. That would require a separate thread in the program doing the periodic flushing, or the language runtime taking over a timer signal that the program could've used for itself, etc. It could be done, especially if the runtime already manages threads, but I don't think I've seen it done in practice.

So instead, flushing is always done every X *bytes,* with a buffer of typically somewhere around 8kB; or in other words, output is only flushed as part of the fwrite() handler. If there are no more writes, the output might never be flushed at all.

> How can I make it more real time? Or print all output within reasonable time?

Since it's buffered by the language runtime, there is no fully generic method to remove that buffering from the outside (except for `stdbuf -o0` for libc buffering, and an ugly workaround of creating a pty for the program's stdout for everything else).

But most runtimes offer a way to control this as part of the program – e.g. in recent Python you can use `sys.stdout.reconfigure(line_buffering=True)` while in C you call `setlinebuf(stdout)`. Most runtimes also don't apply this buffering to stderr – it remains line-buffered even when the output goes to a pipe.

In other words, if the programmer chooses to log important information to stdout, then it's the programmer's responsibility to either adjust buffering *or* to explicitly flush stdout after every message... or write to stderr instead of stdout.

For that matter, most services don't just log to stdout, they log to *syslog* (e.g. using python's `syslog.syslog()`), which is probably a better choice because it lets you specify a message priority (anywhere between 'debug' and 'critical') that users can filter by, instead of everything being a flat wall of text.

Comment: But how come I see the stdout on console without any problem/delay when I run the same app manually, outside systemd? 
Otherwise we wouldn't be able to see any printf below 8KB before program terminates.

Comment: Because the program runtime detects that stdout is going _to a console_ (`sys.stdout.isatty()`) and applies different buffering rules – line-buffered for tty instead of block-buffered for files/pipes/sockets – and there's an implicit flush every time you output a whole line. (I believe all program runtimes do this, whether the buffering is done by Glibc or by Python or by something else.) Compare running `python yourapp` vs `python yourapp |& cat` (with python's stdout becoming a pipe to 'cat').